# Ubuntu, gcc, сборка so, не работают try..catch

Tags: c++, ubuntu, исключения, gcc, try-catch

Собираю библиотеку Lib.so (Ubuntu, gcc 5.4.0), с помощью CMake на Ubuntu.
Параметры сборки такие:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

set(ProjectName "TestMain")
project(${ProjectName})

SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-m64 -std=c++11")
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

set(SOURCE_FILES
    Main.h
    Main.cpp
) 
set_source_files_properties(${SOURCE_FILES} 
                              PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS
                              "-finput-charset=UTF-8 -fPIC")

add_library(${ProjectName} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
set_target_properties( ${ProjectName} PROPERTIES  CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT 1  OUTPUT_NAME ${ProjectName} ) 
target_link_libraries (${ProjectName} "${REQUIRED_LIBRARIES}")
```

Сборка проходит без ошибок.
В одном из методов есть конструкция:

```
try{
...
throw "Error";
...
}
catch (...)
{
...<обработка исключения>
}
```

Если вызвать этот метод, когда срабатывает исключение, вместо того, чтобы попасть в catch, вызывается terminate(), и никакой обработки исключений не возникает, работа вызванного метода завершается, не в зависимости от того, где возник throw.

Вызывается библиотека из 1С (сервер на CentOS), с помощью "ПодключитьВнешнююКомпоненту", все вызовы работают корректно, за исключением этой обработки исключений, собранная под Win dll обрабатывает исключения корректно.

Если сделать код из библиотеки, в консольном приложении, обработка исключений проходит корректно.
Я так полагаю, что это связано именно с shared library, и, видимо, с некорректными флагами сборки.

Гуглил, наткнулся решение добавить флагов -static-libstdc++ или -static-libgcc, но их добавление ничего не меняет, либо я не правильно их добавлял, любое исключение в библиотеке срабатывает как terminate().

Подскажите, в какую сторону посмотреть и/или что можно попробовать сделать, чтобы исключения в .so работали корректно.

Comment: Для начала стоит привести пример кода, воспроизводящий эту проблему. В текущем виде заявленная проблема отсутствует и даже не понятно, находится ли кусок кода в библиотеке или она там вызывается

Comment: Кусок кода находится в библиотеке Lib.so, неважно какой, даже если в try просто написать throw, мгновенно получается terminate() и обработка catch не происходит.

Comment: У нас была похожая проблема, когда собирался код с одной библиотекой libstdc++ (ну или как там называется стандартная библиотека с++), а выполнялся код с другой библиотекой (в смысле с другой версией). Исключения не ловились.

Comment: @bloodpact *"если в try просто написать throw, мгновенно получается terminate()"* - это корректное поведение. *"просто написать throw"* служит для бросания дальше ранее брошенного исключения, а если его нет, то вызывается terminate

Comment: @vegorov Оп уверяет, что этот кусок кода находится в самой библиотеке, соответственно исключение бросается и ловится внутри нее и бинарная несовместимость повлиять на работу этого блока не может.

Comment: @VTT да я вообще не шарю, я просто вспомнил кейс с работы и оставил комментарий.

Comment: @VTT я не спорю, что это корректное поведение. Но после возникновения ошибки, должно попадать в catch, даже учитывая что не было throw, а просто возникла ошибка, реальная. Но в моем случае, при возникновении ошибки, действие метода полностью прекращается, хотя в catch еще был вывод ошибки, и после всей конструкции (try catch) еще куча кода.

Comment: Ок, но вам надо предоставить *минимальный код, воспроизводящий такую проблему*, чтобы другие тоже могли получить такое же  поведение, а то хз, что там у вас в *куче кода*.

Comment: @VTT это невозможно (если я прав и дело в разных версиях библиотек). Если только полностью повторить рабочее окружение.

Comment: @vegorov когда Вы выровняли версии библиотек, исключения стали обрабатываться?

Comment: @vegorov Если проблема была бы в разных версиях библиотек, то воспроизведение было бы делом тривиальным. Собственно без воспроизводящего примера на самом деле даже рано говорить о наличии проблемы.

Comment: @bloodpact да, так всё и было. Правда ещё мы постарались вообще уйти от практики использования исключений. У нас были библиотеки самописные(очень старые, legacy), в документации к которым не было ни слова об исключениях. Ну и было очень весело узнавать об этом от пользователей.

Comment: @vegorov спасибо, на целевой системе была старая версия libgcc (4.8), а собиралось на 5.4.0. Обновил, исключения заработали. Напишите как ответ, я отмечу как решение.

Comment: "Но после возникновения ошибки, должно попадать в catch, даже учитывая что не было throw, а просто возникла ошибка, реальная." - это какая-то чушь. В С++ в `catch` можно попасть только по `throw`. Других вариантов нет. Никаких "реальных ошибок" не существует, только `throw`. И, как правильно заметил VTT, просто `throw` без активного исключения должен сразу напрямую вызывать `terminate()`. Так что ваш пример с "просто `throw`" ни о чем не говорит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У нас была похожая проблема, когда собирался код с одной библиотекой libstdc++ (ну или как там называется стандартная библиотека с++), а выполнялся код с другой библиотекой (в смысле с другой версией). 
Исключения не ловились.

Проверьте версии libgcc - с какой собирается, с какой запускается.